# How to draw arrows and rectangles (for protein sec structure) outside main plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw arrows and rectangles in matplotlib  (to represent protein secondary structure) next to the y-axis of the plot, something like this:

[image]

From [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/arrow_guide.html?highlight=arrows) I got the arrow part, but I can't figure out how to draw it outside the y-axis. Also, is there a way to draw rectangles in addition to arrows? Code and output below:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_tail = 0.0
y_tail = -0.1
x_head = 0.0
y_head = 0.9
dx = x_head - x_tail
dy = y_head - y_tail
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
arrow = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((x_tail, y_tail), (dx, dy),
                                 mutation_scale=50,
                                 transform=axs[0].transAxes)
axs[0].add_patch(arrow)

arrow = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((x_tail, y_tail), (dx, dy),
                                 mutation_scale=100,
                                 transform=axs[1].transAxes)
axs[1].add_patch(arrow)
axs[1].set_xlim(0, 1)
axs[1].set_ylim(0, 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the original approach is somewhat confusing.

Although you can draw rectangles via `mpatch.Rectangle`, I think it is easier to also draw the rectangles via `FancyArrowPatch`. That makes them behave and scale similarly, which is interesting for setting the width. Similarly, the vertical line is also drawn using a `FancyArrowPatch`.

For the positioning, [it seems](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html) you can just give `(tail_x, tail_y)` and `head_x, head_y`. Via [`arrowstyle=`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle.html#matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle) the visual dimensions can be set. Leaving out `head_length=` from the style seems to allow an arrow that looks like a rectangle. For coloring, there are `facecolor=` and `edgecolor=`. And also `color=` which treats `facecolor` and `edgecolor` simultaneously.

`arrow1.set_clip_on(False)` allows to draw the arrows in the margin. Other functions can have a `clip_on=False` parameter. `zorder=` is needed to make the correct lines visible when one is drawn on top of the other.

Here is some example code. The rectangle is drawn twice so the vertical line doesn't show through the hatching. Now x is defined in ['axis coordinates'](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) and y in the standard data coordinates. The 'axis' coordinates go from 0, the left border where usually y-axis is drawn to 1, the right border. Setting x to -0.1 means 10% to the left of the y-axis.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms

x0 = -0.1

arrow_style="simple,head_length=15,head_width=30,tail_width=10"
rect_style="simple,tail_width=25"
line_style="simple,tail_width=1"

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# the x coords of this transformation are axes, and the y coord are data
trans = mtransforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transAxes, ax.transData)

y_tail = 5
y_head = 15
arrow1 = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((x0, y_tail), (x0, y_head), arrowstyle=arrow_style, transform=trans)
arrow1.set_clip_on(False)
ax.add_patch(arrow1)

y_tail = 40
y_head = 60
arrow2 = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((x0, y_tail), (x0, y_head), arrowstyle=arrow_style, facecolor='gold', edgecolor='black', linewidth=1, transform=trans)
arrow2.set_clip_on(False)
ax.add_patch(arrow2)

y_tail = 20
y_head = 40
rect_backgr = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((x0, y_tail), (x0, y_head), arrowstyle=rect_style, color='white', zorder=0, transform=trans)
rect_backgr.set_clip_on(False)
rect = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((x0, y_tail), (x0, y_head), arrowstyle=rect_style, fill=False, color='orange', hatch='///', transform=trans)
rect.set_clip_on(False)
ax.add_patch(rect_backgr)
ax.add_patch(rect)

line = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((x0, 0), (x0, 80), arrowstyle=line_style, color='orange', transform=trans, zorder=-1)
line.set_clip_on(False)
ax.add_patch(line)

ax.set_xlim(0, 30)
ax.set_ylim(0, 80)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]